# How to make a better algorithm given this code?

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode

i have this algo and i want to know if it's possible to make it better(less complexity):

```
 for i = 3 to A.length 
  for j = 2 to i − 1
    for k = 1 to j − 1
      if |A[i] − A[j]| = = |A[j] − A[k]| or |A[i] − A[k]| = = |A[j] − A[k]|
           return true
 return false
```

The complexity has to be O(n^3), and the sentence after "or" is just 
     A[i]=A[j]

I am not sure that could exist a better algorithm...

Comment: What is this algorithm for? What does it do?

Comment: Are you trying to determine if the array contains a triple which consists of two points together with their midpoint?

Comment: Also, your claim that 'the sentence after "or" is just A[i]=A[j]' makes little sense since `|A[i] − A[k]| = = |A[j] − A[k]|` is not equivalent to `A[i] == A[j]`

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce to `O(n^2)` time (but increase space complexity) by hashing the counts of differences.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the array beforehand and use binary-search to bring down the time complexity from *O(N^3)* to *O(N^2 logN)*.

Pseudo code -

```
sort(A)

for i = 1 to A.length - 2
    for j = i + 1 to A.length - 1
        //search for an element A[k] such that A[k]-A[j] == A[j]-A[i]
        if binary_search(A, 2 * A[j] - A[i], j + 1, A.length)
            return True
return False
```

`binary_search(A, x, i, j)` returns `true` if `x` is present in `A` between indices `i` and `j`.

Unlike the other solution involving hashing, you won't need any additional space.

Comment: @Kittsil We're interested in absolute values and if you're going to compare absolute differences, you have to consider both the condition. Just imagine when you have to find x for |p - q| == |q - x|.

Comment: @Kittsil unfortunately, I didn't see the edit suggestion. If you make another edit with updated indices, I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: This really is the best answer if space is constrained to O(n).